# O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?

Tags: python

Uso **"%"** ou **".format"**? Acho que o último é mais recente, mas tem algum outro aspecto a ser levado em conta na hora de decidir qual usar?

Comment: Há uma PEP inteira a ser considerada: [PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o https://dbader.org/blog/python-string-formatting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Para versões 3.6+, utilize as *f-strings* para a interpolação: [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

Para versões 3+, anteriores a 3.6, prefira sempre utilizar o método `format`, ele foi definido justamente para substituir o `%` - para versão 3.6 ou superior, ler [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). A PEP que sugeriu tal alteração foi a PEP 3101:

[PEP 3101 -- Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

E alguns dos pontos que levaram a tal mudança são:

1. O operador `%` é um operador binário, então sempre receberá dois parâmetros. O primeiro já está reservado à *string* que será formatada, então a linguagem fica limitada a passar todos os valores da formatação através do segundo parâmetro;

   Isso traz algumas implicações:

   - O parâmetro que possui os valores de formatação necessariamente será um tipo composto, pois deve possuir a capacidade de armazenar múltiplos valores;

     ```
     >>> string % parameters
     ```
   - Fica-se limitado a sempre utilizar apenas parâmetros posicionais, ao passá-los através de uma tupla, ou parâmetros nomeados, ao passá-los através de um dicionário, mas nunca ambos concomitantemente;

     ```
     >>> '%s %s' % ('john', 'doe')  # posicional
     john doe

     >>> '%(first)s %(last)s' % {'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe'}  # nomeado
     john doe
     ```
   - Prejudica a semântica, pois não é esperado que um operador binário faça a formatação de uma *string*;

     ```
     >>> 5 % 2  # Calcula o resto da divisão
     1

     >>> string % parameters  # Formata string????
     ```
2. Não é possível utilizar ferramentas da linguagem como *tuple deconstructing* ou *dict deconstructing* para facilitar a passagem de valores;

   ```
   >>> name = ['john', 'doe']
   >>> '%s %s' % (*name)
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   ```

Fora isso, outras funcionalidades foram adicionadas ao novo estilo, quando utilizado o método `format`:

1. Utilizar parâmetros posicionais, mas utilizá-los em ordem sorteada;

   ```
   >>> '{1}, {0}'.format('john', 'doe')
   doe, john
   ```
2. Definir espaçamento na *string* substituindo o caractere a ser exibido: no estilo antigo, sempre é exibido um espaço em branco;

   ```
   >>> '{:_<10}'.format('john')
   john______
   ```
3. Centralizar o conteúdo com referência ao espaço disponível;

   ```
   >>> '{:_^10}'.format('john')
   +++john+++
   ```
4. Ao utilizar números sinalizados, é possível controlar a posição do sinal;

   ```
   >>> '{:=5d}'.format(-3)
   -   3
   >>> '{:=+5d}'.format(3)
   +   3
   ```
5. O método `format` aceita parâmetros nomeados para definir os valores, não dependendo mais de dicionários ou tuplas;

   ```
   >>> '{first} {last}'.format(first='john', last='doe')
   john doe
   ```

   O que permite utilizar *tuple deconstructing* ou *dict deconstructing*:

   ```
   >>> name = ('john', 'doe')
   >>> '{0} {1}'.format(*name)
   john doe

   >>> name = {'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe'}
   >>> '{first} {last}'.format(**name)
   john doe
   ```
6. É possível acessar valores diretamente da *string*;

   ```
   >>> john = {'first': 'john', 'last': 'doe'}
   >>> '{name[first]} {name[last]}'.format(name=john)
   john doe
   ```
7. De igual forma, é possível acessar atributos do objeto;

   ```
   >>> 'Nome do arquivo: {0.name}'.format(open('arquivo.txt'))
   Nome do arquivo: arquivo.txt
   ```
8. É possível que objetos assumam o controle de sua própria formatação, assim como acontece com o objeto `datetime.datetime`;

   ```
   >>> from datetime import datetime
   >>> '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M}'.format(datetime.now())
   2017-12-11 20:52
   ```

   Isso é possível pois o método `format` buscará pelo método `__format__` do objeto;
9. É possível parametrizar o próprio formato com seus valores;

   ```
   >>> '{:_{align}{width}}'.format('john', align='^', width='10')
   ___john___
   >>> '{:_{align}{width}}'.format('john', align='>', width='10')
   ______john
   ```

**Outras referências**

[1] [Using % and .format() for great good!](https://pyformat.info/)

[2] [Classe `string.template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template)

[3] [Lista de e-mails: String formating operations in python 3k](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-April/000285.html)