# Erro de tipo: nem todas as strings convertidas durante a formatação

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Estou tentando fazer um jogo de par ou ímpar. O problema é que toda vez que a soma da minha jogada com a do computador dá 'par' aparece essa mensagem de erro. Já tentei outros tipos de formatação e sempre aparece o mesmo erro. Além disso, essa linha é praticamente a mesma da de cima, mas a linhalogo acima não dá erro, mas por algum motivo, essa linha dá. Segue o código

```
from random import randint

pc = randint(0,10)

print(' =-'*20)
print('VAMOS JOGAR PAR OU ÍMPAR')
print(' =-'*20)

vitoria = 0


while True:
    vc = int(input('Diga um valor: '))
    j = str(input('Par ou Ímpar? [P/I]: '))
    while vc < 0 or vc > 10:
        vc = int(input('Jogada inválida. Digite um número de 1 a 10: '))
        j = str(input('Par ou Ímpar? [P/I]: '))
    soma = vc + pc
    if soma % 2 == 0:
        print(f'Você jogou {vc} e o computador jogou {pc}.Total de {soma} deu PAR')
        soma = 'p'
    if soma %2  != 0:
        print(f'Você jogou {vc} e o computador jogou {pc}.Total de {soma} deu IMPAR')
        soma = 'i'
    if j != soma:
        break
    vitoria = vitoria + 1
print('VOCÊ PERDEU!')
print('=-'*20)
print(f'GAME OVER! Você venceu {vitoria} vezes')
```

**Print do erro**

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Edit: Consegui contornar o problema colocando um 'else' no lugar de outra condição 'if'. Mas ainda gostaria de saber por que isso aconteceu

Comment: Quando o resultado é par, entra na primeira condição, onde você define `soma` igual a `'p'`, o que não parece fazer muito sentido, mas o erro ocorre logo abaixo, quando você tenta calcular de novo o resto de divisão por 2. Quanto vale o resto de divisão de P por 2? Vale lembrar que a mensagem de erro que dá é sobre formatação de *string*

Comment: Eu defino soma = p (par) se a soma da minha jogada + a do CPU for par e soma = i (impar) se se a minha jogada (vc) + jogada da CPU (pc)der um resultado ímpar. O resto da divisão de p por 2 é zero. Mas o valor 'p' é atribuido depois que é verfificado que o resto da divisão por 2 é zero. Quando o programa pergunta se quero par ou impar, devo responder com 'p' (par) ou 'i' (impar). Essa string deve coincidir com a soma para que eu ganhe a partida

Comment: Mas você verifica de novo na linha de baixo... E não, resto de divisão de "p" por 2 não existe. Você não consegue dividir uma letra por um inteiro.

Comment: Mas é 'soma / 2', e não 'p/2'. A variavel  'soma' possui um valor numerico atribuído a ela. Agora que vi

Comment: E na linha `soma = 'p'`?

Comment: Nessa linha, o valor soma foi atribuido a uma letra depois de ter sido verificado se essa variavel dava uma divisao inteira por 2. Eu nao dividi uma string por 2. Mas eu consertei esse problema colocando UM ELSE.

Comment: Na linha de baixo, você faz novamente `soma % 2`. Neste ponto `soma` é uma letra, não um inteiro.

Answer (score 1):

Seu erro está em utilizar o mesmo objeto, `soma`, para armazenar tanto o resultado da soma dos números como a letra que identifica o resultado. Além de ser uma péssima abordagem, pois não deixa o código legível, abre espaço para cometer erros tal como cometeu.

Quando o resultado da soma dos valores é par, a condição do primeiro `if`, da linha 19, é satisfeita e seu bloco de código é executado. Na linha 21, dentro do `if`, você muda o valor de `soma` para `'p`', a fim de indicar que o resultado foi par, porém, na linha imediatamente abaixo você tenta calcular novamente o resto da divisão de `soma` por 2; neste momento, `soma` não é mais um valor inteiro, mas sim uma *string* `'p'` e, no Python, o operador resto serve para formatação de *string*, o que explica a mensagem de erro. Esta incoerência do Python já cfoi corrigida, mas não omitida, através da implementação do método `str.format`, bem como descrevi nessa pergunta:

[Formatação de caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)

Para o seu problema, a solução mais simples é alterar em um dos pontos do programa o nome do objeto; por exemplo, ao invés de fazer `soma = 'p'`, fazer algo como `resultado = 'p'` e no final verificar se `j != resultado`.

Uma alternativa para seu código seria:

```
from random import randint

print('=-'*20)
print('VAMOS JOGAR PAR OU ÍMPAR')
print('=-'*20)

vitorias = 0

while True:
    while True:
        voce = int(input("Que número entre 0 e 10 você jogará? "))
        if not 0 < voce < 10:
            print("Valor inválido, diga um número entre 0 e 10")
            continue
        break
    while True:
        resposta = input("[P]ar ou [I]mpar?").upper()
        if resposta not in ('P', 'I'):
            print("Entre com P para par ou I para ímpar")
            continue
        break
    computador = randint(0, 10)
    soma = voce + computador
    resultado = 'P' if soma % 2 == 0 else 'I'
    print(f"Você: {voce} / Computador: {computador} / Soma: {soma}")
    if resultado == resposta:
        vitorias += 1
    else:
        break
print('=-'*20)
print(f'GAME OVER! Você venceu {vitorias} vezes')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GoodnaturedBubblyAbyssiniangroundhornbill)</sup>

**Considerações**

Para explicar as diferenças entre os códigos, vejamos:

1. A leitura do valor que o jogador quer é feito dentro de um laço infinito; isso se dá porque não sabemos quantas vezes ele entrará com um valor inválido e evita você saber previamente o valor - ou seja, você só lê em um lugar do código apenas, não precisa chamar duas vezes `input()` para a mesma coisa (redundância);
2. A validação do valor se dá com `not 0 < voce < 10`, ao invés de `voce < 0 or voce  > 10`, o que deixa o código muito mais legível (*Readability counts*);
3. A leitura da resposta sobre par ou ímpar do usuário também é validada, garantindo que o mesmo indique uma resposta que o programa saiba lidar - o que seu código original não faz. A lógica é exatamente a mesma para ler o valor inteiro, mas verificando se a resposta do jogador foi `'P'` ou `'I'`. Também utilizei o método `str.upper()` para garantir que a entrada do jogador seja sempre em caixa alta, o que lhe permite entrar com `'p'` ou `'i'` também;
4. Como comentei anteriormente, utilizei um objeto diferente para armazenar o resultado do jogo e mantive o objeto `soma` para armazenar a soma dos valores. O objeto `resultado` receberá `'P'` quando a soma for par e `'I'` quando ímpar, assim como no seu código, mas de uma forma mais simples;
5. Outro detalhe importante foi que coloquei a função `randint()` para dentro do laço infinito, para que a resposta do computador seja diferente a cada rodada. Da maneira que você fez, o valor será o mesmo em todas elas;

Comment: Acho que agora entendi.Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeM.P. adicionei uma solução própria ao problema como alternativa e comentei as principais diferenças. Recomendo que leia.

Comment: Obrigado @Anderson Carlos Woss vou ler. O programa ja esta funcionando. Coloquei um 'else' no lugar do segundo if e atribui os valores 'p' e 'i' à variavel 'resultado'. Mas tem algumas modificações que eu nao tinha feito.