# Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolação-de-string

Por exemplo, no PHP, podemos fazer assim:

```
$preco = 200;
$unidades = 10;

$texto_final = "O produto custa {$preco} reais e restam {$unidades} unidades.";
```

É possível fazer algo semelhante em Python ou é necessário concatenar sempre?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para versões anteriores a 3.6, prefira sempre utilizar o método `str.format` e eu explico o porquê nesta pergunta:

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)

Já, a partir da versão 3.6, foi adicionado um novo modo de realizar a interpolação: as [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)). Elas são *strings* definidas com o prefixo `f` e podem conter expressões entre chaves que serão analisadas em tempo de execução.

```
preco = 200
unidades = 10

print(f"O produto custa {preco} reais e restam {unidades} unidades.")
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/WillingHardHen)</sup>

É permitido, inclusive, utilizar as regras de formação que o método `str.format` possui, tal como:

```
pi = 3.14159

print(f'O valor de pi é {pi: >10.3}')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MushyAlertEuropeanfiresalamander)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Podes fazer assim:

```
preco = 200
unidades = 10

texto_final = "O produto custa R$ %.2f reais e restam %s unidades." % (preco, unidades)

print(texto_final)

# Outros exemplos

nome = 'Thon';
sobre = 'de Souza';

print("%s %s" % (nome, sobre))

print("{} {}".format(nome, sobre))
print("{nome} {sobre}".format(nome="João", sobre="da Silva"))
print("{sobre} {nome}".format(nome="João", sobre="da Silva"))

preco = 162.58

print("R$ %.1f" % (preco))
print("R$ %.2f" % (preco))
print("R$ %.3f" % (preco))
```

- **%s** - String (ou qualquer objeto com uma representação de seqüência de caracteres, como números)
- **%d** - Inteiros
- **%f** - Números de ponto flutuante
- **%.<número de dígitos>f** - Números de pontos flutuantes com uma quantidade fixa de dígitos à direita do ponto.
- **%x/%X** - Inteiros na representação hexadecimal (minúsculas / maiúsculas)

> Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PaleScrawnyCassowary)

#### Referências

- [String Formatting - Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string-formatting)
- [Custom String Formatting - Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)