# Nem todos os argumentos foram convertidos durante a formatação da string. O que isso significa?

Tags: python

```
f=open("arquivo.txt", 'w')
```

Estou fazendo um código para plotar uma gaussiana sobre o caminhante aleatório (Mecanica Estatística) e está dando esse erro na hora de salvar no arquivo meu "count". Esse é o código:

```
for j in range (0,t):
    count=0
    for i in range (0,100):
        x[i]=randint(0,1)
        if x[i]==1:
            count=count+1
            f.write=('0.1f\n'%(count))
f.close()
```

Esse é o erro:

```
File "estat", line 23, in <module>
    f.write=('0.1f\n'%(count))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

O que pode ser?

Comment: Por favor, poste o código inteiro para uma melhor verificação.

Comment: Python não é minha área, mas você já tentou converter sua variável `count` para string? O problema pode ser esse, tente assim `f.write=('0.1f\n'%(str(count)))`

Answer (score 2):

Falta um `%` antes do `0.1f`. O `=` ali também é desnecessário e daria problema. Faça:

```
f.write('%0.1f\n'%(count))
```

Ou com `format`:

```
f.write('{:.1f}\n'.format(count))
```

Answer (score 2):

Bem como o Pedro falou, sua sintaxe possui vários erros. O erro citado é porque você utilizou o operador `%` em *string*, que é utilizado para formatação, mas sua *string* não possui nenhum template a ser substituído. Ela é uma *string* literal - e é a ausência do `%` precedendo o valor `0.1f` que causa isso.

Além disso, o `=` após o `f.write` fará com que você sobrescreva o objeto ao invés de chamá-lo - o que não daria necessariamente erro, mas não iria gerar o resultado esperado, com certeza.

Se estiver utilizando Python 3.6 ou superior, poderá utilizar as *f-string*:

```
f.write(f'{count:.1f}\n')
```

Falei um pouco disso aqui:

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

Também acredito que seja útil você ler sobre gerenciadores de contextos para utilizar junto ao `with`.

- [Para que serve o with no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49238/5878)

Então, uma alternativa ao seu código seria:

```
with open('arquivo.txt', 'w') as f:
    for j in range (0, t):
        count = 0
        for i in range(0, 100):
            x[i] = randint(0, 1)
            if x[i] == 1:
                count = count + 1
                f.write(f'{count:.1f}\n')
```

Isso porque não dá para saber ao certo o que são as outras variáveis. Por exemplo, `count` será um número inteiro, então precisa mesmo formatá-lo como ponto flutuante?