# Formatação de saída de dados no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

Minha dúvida é sobre formatação de saída de dados do programa. 
Estou resolvendo um dos exercícios do `wiki.python.org`, cuja entrada dos dados é a seguinte:

```
alexandre       456123789
anderson        1245698456
antonio         123456456
carlos          91257581
cesar           987458
rosemary        789456125
```

Esta entrada foi salva em um arquivo tipo `.txt` que deve ser aberto pelo programa, a saída dos dados deve ser feita de forma semelhante a esta:

```
ACME Inc.               Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nr.  Usuário        Espaço utilizado     % do uso

1    alexandre       434,99 MB             16,85%
2    anderson       1187,99 MB             46,02%
3    antonio         117,73 MB              4,56%
4    carlos           87,03 MB              3,37%
5    cesar             0,94 MB              0,04%
6    rosemary        752,88 MB             29,16%

Espaço total ocupado: 2581,57 MB
Espaço médio ocupado: 430,26 MB
```

Para resolver o problema eu escrevi o seguinte programa:

```
soma = 0
nome, espaco = [], []
a = open("usuarios.txt")
for line in a:
    b = line.strip().split(" ")
    nome.append(b[0])
    espaco.append(b[1])
print("ACME Inc.               Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("Nr.",end = "  ")
print("Usuário",end = "      ")
print("Espaço utilizado",end = "      ")
print("% do uso")
print(" ")
for j in range(len(nome)):
    espaco[j] = int(espaco[j])
    soma += espaco[j]
for i in range(len(nome)):
    print(i+1,end = "    ")
    print(nome[i],end = "    ")
    espaco[i] = int(espaco[i])
    print("{:.2f} MB".format(espaco[i]/(1024*1024)),end = "    ")
    print("{:.2f}%".format((espaco[i]/soma)*100))
print("")
print("Espaço total ocupado: {:.2f} MB".format(soma/(1024*1024)))
print("Espaço médio ocupado: {:.2f} MB".format((soma/(1024*1024))/len(espaco)))
```

Minha saída de dados é a seguinte:

```
ACME Inc.               Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nr.  Usuário      Espaço utilizado      % do uso

1    alexandre    434.99 MB    16.85%
2    anderson    1187.99 MB    46.02%
3    antonio    117.74 MB    4.56%
4    carlos    87.03 MB    3.37%
5    cesar    0.94 MB    0.04%
6    rosemary    752.88 MB    29.16%

Espaço total ocupado: 2581.58 MB
Espaço médio ocupado: 430.26 MB
```

Como podem observar, a saída está toda torta, não tem os valores exatamente um embaixo do outro, como pede o enunciado. Como faço esta formatação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você formulou de forma errônea a solução. Não é o tamanho do espaçamento entre os valores que é constante, mas sim a largura disponível para cada coluna.

Se você reparar na saída desejada:

```
1    alexandre       434,99 MB             16,85%
2    anderson       1187,99 MB             46,02%
3    antonio         117,73 MB              4,56%
4    carlos           87,03 MB              3,37%
5    cesar             0,94 MB              0,04%
6    rosemary        752,88 MB             29,16%
```

Verá que:

- A primeira coluna possui 5 caracteres de largura, alinhada à esquerda;
- A segunda coluna possui 12 caracteres de largura, alinhada à esquerda;
- A terceira coluna possui 13 caracteres de largura, alinhada à direta;
- A quarta coluna possui 19 caracteres de largura, alinhada à direita;

Assim, considerando os dados:

```
número, nome, espaço, porcentagem = 1, 'alexandre', '434,99 MB', '16,85%'
```

Você pode formatar a linha utilizando *f-string*:

```
f'{número: <5}{nome: <12}{espaço: >13}{porcentagem: >19}'
```

Em que a instrução `{número: <5}` significa:

- Utilize o valor do objeto `número`;
- Utilize o espaço em branco como caractere de preenchimento;
- Alinhe à esquerda;
- Ocupando pelo menos 5 caracteres de largura;

De modo equivalente aos outros objetos. Você pode ler mais em:

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

A forma que eu resolveria é:

```
output = '''
ACME Inc.               Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nr.  Usuário        Espaço utilizado     % do uso

{usuarios}

Espaço total ocupado: {total:.2f} MB
Espaço médio ocupado: {media:.2f} MB
'''

def format_user_info(i, name, space, total):
    percentage = 100*space/total
    return f'{i: <5}{name: <12}{space: >10.2f} MB{percentage: >18.2f}%'

users = []

with open('data.txt') as stream:
    for line in stream:
        name, space = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        users.append((name, int(space)/1024**2))

total = sum(user[1] for user in users)
media = total / len(users)

users = [
    format_user_info(i, name, space, total) 
        for i, (name, space) in enumerate(users, 1)
]

print(output.format(usuarios='\n'.join(users), total=total, media=media))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/EachTurboPagerecognition)</sup>

O que produziria a saída:

```
ACME Inc.               Uso do espaço em disco pelos usuários
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nr.  Usuário        Espaço utilizado     % do uso

1    alexandre       434.99 MB             16.85%
2    anderson       1187.99 MB             46.02%
3    antonio         117.74 MB              4.56%
4    carlos           87.03 MB              3.37%
5    cesar             0.94 MB              0.04%
6    rosemary        752.88 MB             29.16%

Espaço total ocupado: 2581.58 MB
Espaço médio ocupado: 430.26 MB
```