# Quebrar linhas em um determinado espaço de caracteres em Python

Tags: python

Olá, criei um programa em Python para criar uma sequencia de P.A., só que quero que o print do resultado dos numeros quebrem apos 100 caracteres, para o resultado ficar dentro da tela.
alguem pode me ajudar??

```
texto = 'Calculadora de Progressão Aritmética'
print('=' * 100)
print(f'{texto: ^100}')
print('=' * 100)
a1 = input('Digite o primeiro termo da P.A.: ')
r = input('Digite a razão da P.A.: ')
ter = input('Quantos termos da P.A. deseja visualizar? ')
cont = 0
if a1.isdigit() and r.isdigit() and ter.isdigit() or '-' in a1 or '-' in r:
    for i in range(0, int(ter)):
        cont = cont + 1
        if True:
            an = int(a1) + (cont - 1) * int(r)
        print(f'{an}', end=', ')
    print(f'sao os {ter} primeiros termos da P.A.!', end=' ')
else:
    print('Digite somente números e/ou o número de termos é positivo.')
```

Comment: Bem vindo. Próximos blocos de código, insira ``` para abrir e ``` para fechar o bloco de código

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359166/formatação-de-saída-de-dados-no-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou postando minha resposta como um complemento à [resposta do @Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/422159/6333). Sua pergunta especifica que você quer tratar sua string de resultado para ter no máximo 100 para que seu conteúdo caiba na tela.
Minha resposta aborda o problema de maneira diferente, por isso quero deixar aqui como alternativa, para que algum futuro visitante tenha outras opções de solução para o mesmo problema.

Ao invés de limitar o número de caracteres por linha, você pode limitar quantos termos por linha você quer e mostrá-los como "colunas".

## Código

```
from itertools import cycle

a1, r, ter = 1, 2, 30

# nosso "paginador"
itens_por_linha = 6
ends = [''] * (itens_por_linha - 1)
ends.append('\n')
# ends = ['', '', '', '', '', '\n']

for item, end in zip(range(a1, r * ter, r), cycle(ends)):
    print(f"{item: >5d}", end=end)
```

<sup>Veja rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-422186-6333)</sup>

## Resultado

```
    1    3    5    7    9   11
   13   15   17   19   21   23
   25   27   29   31   33   35
   37   39   41   43   45   47
   49   51   53   55   57   59
```

---

## Explicação do código

#### `range(start, stop, step)` ([#docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range))

Como você mesmo já usou no seu código, eu uso o range para gerar a P.A. Sendo:

- `a1` o parâmetro `start`;
- `r * ter` será o `stop` para garantir que o tamanho do range gerado tenha exatamente N elementos definidos pela variável `ter`;
- `r` será o `step`

```
a1, r, ter = 1, 2, 10
pa = list(range(a1, r * ter, r))

print(pa)
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
print(len(pa))
# 10
```

#### `print(*objects, end='\n')` ([#docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print))

Na minha solução, faço uso do parâmetro `end` que a função [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) aceita para controlar quando devo quebrar a linha.

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
# Resultado:
# 0
# 1
# 2

for i in range(3):
    print(i, end=" ")
# Resultado:
# 0 1 2
```

#### `zip(*iterables)` ([#docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip))

O função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) é utilizada para percorrer N iteráveis "paralelamente". Exemplo:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
letras = ['A', 'B', 'C']
simbolos = ['!', '@', '#', '$']

for num, letra in zip(nums, letras):
    print(f"{letra}{num}", end=', ')
# A1, B2, C3

for num, letra, simb in zip(nums, letras, simbolos):
    print(f"{letra}{num}({simb})", end=', ')
# A1(!), B2(@), C3(#)
```

Note que `zip` sempre para de iterar no seu iterável mais curto, no exemplo acima `simbolos` tem tamanho 4, porém a iteração para após o 3º item pois `nums` e `letras` têm apenas 3 itens.

Você pode usar o `zip` fora do `for`, pois o retorno de `zip` é um iterável também. Veja:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]
letras = ['A', 'B', 'C']
simbolos = ['!', '@', '#', '$']

lista_1 = list(zip(nums, letras))
lista_2 = list(zip(nums, letras, simbolos))


print(lista_1)
# [(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C')]

print(lista_2)
# [(1, 'A', '!'), (2, 'B', '@'), (3, 'C', '#')]
```

#### `itertools.cycle(iterable)` ([#docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle))

Na minha solução utilizo o [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) para criar uma repetição infinita dos caracteres que quero usar como `end` do `print`. Veja um exemplo simples:

```
from itertools import cycle

abc = cycle("ABC")
nums = range(1, 6)

for letra, num in zip(abc, nums):
    print(f"{letra}{num}", end=", ")
# A1, B2, C3, A4, B5, 

par_impar = ('par', 'ímpar')
nums = range(5)

lista = list(zip(nums, par_impar))
print(lista)
# [(0, 'par'), (1, 'ímpar'), (2, 'par'), (3, 'ímpar'), (4, 'par')]
```

#### String formatting

No print da solução uso a formatação `>5d`, que significa:

```
print(f"{item: >5d}")
#             │││└── "d": formatação para números inteiros
#             ││└─── "5": largura do resultado
#             │└──── ">": alinhamento a direita
#             └───── " ": preenchimento com espaços
```

Exemplos:

```
item = 123

print(f"{item: >5d}")  # "  123"
print(f"{item: <5d}")  # "123  "
print(f"{item: ^5d}")  # " 123 "
print(f"{item:_>5d}")  # "__123"
print(f"{item:0>7d}")  # "0000123"
```

Veja [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/) e a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) para maiores informações.

---

Dito isso, agora você já deve entender o que o meu código faz, basicamente:

- Cria a string que será usada como separador entre os termos da PA.

  Se `itens_por_linha` for `4`, cria um iterador infinito que gera 3 strings vazias e 1 quebra de linha (`['', '', '', '\n', '', '', '', '\n', '', ...]`).
- Estes caracteres são usados pelo `print` para definir se o algoritmo quebrará a linha, ou *printará* o termo na mesma linha.
- Percorre a PA e os o gerador de limitadores "paralelamente" usando `zip`
- Printa o resultado

Comment: Muito boa sacada, Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Para isso, utilize a bilbioteca `textwrap` que possui a função `wrap` que recebe o texto e a quantidade máxima de caracteres que você deseja por linha, retornando uma lista de *strings* que respeitam o tamanho definido.

Se você tem a *string* referente a sua P.A.:

```
pa = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15'
```

Para exibí-la em múltiplas linhas com tamanho máximo de 10, por exemplo, bastaria fazer:

```
from textwrap import wrap

for line in wrap(pa, width=10):
    print(line)
```

A saída seria:

```
1, 2, 3,
4, 5, 6,
7, 8, 9,
10, 11,
12, 13,
14, 15
```

Perceba que não necessariamente as linhas terão 10 caracteres de tamanho, mas todas respeitarão o tamanho **máximo** de 10, sem quebrar o conteúdo ao meio.

Mudando para `width=30` teriamos:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Fonte: https://xkcd.com/353/</sup>

Comment: Aproveitou ainda para fazer graça na resposta kkk

Answer (score 0):

Comentei as partes que eu inseri. Achei melhor quebrar pro número e não simplesmente pelo tamanho da linha para evitar que um número fique quebrado entre linhas.

```
texto = 'Calculadora de Progressão Aritmética'
print('=' * 100)
print(f'{texto: ^100}')
print('=' * 100)
a1 = input('Digite o primeiro termo da P.A.: ')
r = input('Digite a razão da P.A.: ')
ter = input('Quantos termos da P.A. deseja visualizar? ')
cont = 0
linha = 0  ### Nova linha de código
if a1.isdigit() and r.isdigit() and ter.isdigit() or '-' in a1 or '-' in r:
    for i in range(0, int(ter)):
        cont = cont + 1
        if True:
            an = int(a1) + (cont - 1) * int(r)
        print(f'{an}', end=', ')
        ### Novas lihas de código ###
        if linha>=100:
            print('\n')
            linha = 0
        else:
            linha += len(str(an)) + 2 # tamanho do número e mais dois dígitos do espaço e vírgula
        ##############################
    print(f'sao os {ter} primeiros termos da P.A.!', end=' ')
else:
    print('Digite somente números e/ou o número de termos é positivo.')
```

Outra solução seria somar dotas as respostas em um texto como `resposta += f'{an}, '` e usar `resposta[i:100+i]` dentro de um `for`, mas quebrariam números no meio.