# Python 3.8 - Como formatar a exibição dos elementos de uma lista em coluna

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Olá.

Meu código atualmente:

Para preencher a lista:

```
lista = []

def preenche_Lista():

        while True:
                espaco ="|______"
                nomeAluno = str(input('Qual o nome do estudante? - Digite FIM para encerrar -> ')).upper()
                elemento = nomeAluno+(espaco * 7)
                lista.append(elemento)
                if nomeAluno == "FIM":
                        break
```

Para exibir a lista:

```
def exibe_Lista(lista):
   x = 0
   print('Lista completa dos alunos cadastrados:\n{}'.format('*' * 50))
   while x < len(lista):
            elemento = lista[x]
            print(elemento)
            x += 1
```

Com essas duas funções eu estou alcançando esse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém o resultado desejado é:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sou iniciante na linguagem então não tenho menor ideia de onde eu posso fazer essa formatação.
desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você precisa acha nome que tem mais caracteres e depois calcular a diferença das outras e adicionar os espaços dependendo da diferença.

Comment: Existe um pergunta semelhante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/359166/formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-sa%C3%ADda-de-dados-no-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Além da solução em si (como formatar corretamente a saída), há outros detalhes a se atentar no seu código.

A função que preenche a lista está inserindo na `lista` que foi criada fora da função. Ou seja, essa função só funciona para aquela lista específica. E se você quiser outra lista? E se a lista já tiver algum elemento antes? Então a ideia é que a função crie a lista ali dentro e a retorne.

Sem contar que, da forma que você fez o *loop*, a string `"FIM"` também é inserida na lista, como se fosse um nome de aluno. E [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário.

Já para percorrer a lista, não precisa usar um `while` com a variável sendo incrementada até `len(lista)`. Em Python você pode percorrer listas e outros objetos iteráveis com `for...in`.

E para formatar os dados, basta usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). Além disso, como você informou que está usando Python 3.8, já pode usar [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (mais detalhes abaixo).

Mas há um pequeno detalhe. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/458870/112052) sugeriu usar um tamanho fixo, como 10, por exemplo. Mas e se for digitado algum nome com mais que 10 caracteres? Uma alternativa seria escolher um tamanho "grande o suficiente" para que "nunca" tenhamos um nome maior. Mas outra alternativa é verificar o tamanho dos nomes e usar o maior deles como o tamanho a ser usado na formatação.

Então ficaria assim:

```
def preenche_lista():
    lista = [] # cria a lista dentro da função
    maior = 0
    while True:
        nome = input('Qual o nome do estudante? - Digite FIM para encerrar -> ').upper()
        if nome == "FIM": # se for "FIM", não insere na lista e retorna a lista e o maior tamanho
            return lista, maior
        if len(nome) > maior: # verifica se o nome digitado é o maior
            maior = len(nome)
        lista.append(nome)

# pega a lista de alunos e o tamanho do maior nome
alunos, tamanho = preenche_lista()

for aluno in alunos:
    # usa o tamanho do maior nome como o tamanho da formatação
    print(f'{aluno:<{tamanho}} ', '|_____' * 7, '|', sep='')
```

Ao fazer `{aluno:<{tamanho}}`, o nome do aluno é alinhado à esquerda, e `tamanho` indica o  tamanho a ser usado para o nome, preenchendo com espaços caso o nome seja menor. O `f` antes das aspas indica que é uma *f-string*, o que permite essa sintaxe de colocar a variável e as opções de formatação entre chaves. Exemplo de saída:

```
FULANO                       |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
CICLANO                      |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
ALCEBIADES DA SILVA DE SOUZA |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

---

Se quiser manter a função que exibe os alunos, a ideia é que ela receba como parâmetros a lista e o tamanho:

```
def exibe_lista(alunos, tamanho):
    print(f'Lista completa dos alunos cadastrados:\n{"*" * (44 + tamanho)}')
    for aluno in alunos:
        print(f'{aluno:<{tamanho}} ', '|_____' * 7, '|', sep='')
```

Aí bastaria chamar:

```
alunos, tamanho = preenche_lista()
exibe_lista(alunos, tamanho)
```

Ou ainda:

```
exibe_lista(*preenche_lista())
```

No caso, o asterisco serve para que os valores retornados por `preenche_lista` (a lista e o tamanho) sejam passados como parâmetros para `exibe_lista` (veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) para mais detalhes). Essa forma é interessante se você não vai usar esses valores para mais nada (pois aí nem vale a pena guardá-los em variáveis).

Exemplo de saída:

```
Lista completa dos alunos cadastrados:
************************************************************************
FULANO                       |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
CICLANO                      |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
ALCEBIADES DA SILVA DE SOUZA |_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, esclareceu bastante. Essas duas funções fazem parte de um outro programa, mas com os seus toques eu vou otimizar tanto elas como o programa em sí. 
valeu!

Comment: @MatheusTaurino Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos, [**vc também poderá votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar o método `format` com o tipo de formatação `:<` para adicionar uma quantidade X de espaços à direita da string, caso seja necessário. Veja o código de exemplo abaixo:

```
alunos = []

for aluno in range(5):
    alunos.append(input(f"Digite o nome do {aluno + 1}º aluno: "))

for aluno in alunos:
    print("{:<10}".format(aluno), "|_____|" * 7)
```