# Notação cientifica em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pensei em fazer uma fórmula de eletrostática que desse o resultado em notação cientifica, mas não sei como faço para deixar em notação científica.

Há alguma biblioteca para isso?

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n "))
e = 1.6*10**-19
q = int(input("Digite o valor de Q "))
resultado = n*e


if(q !=0):
    resultado = q / e
    print(f'{resultado:.0e}')
else:
    resultado = n*e
    print(f'{resultado:.0e}')
```

Comment: Uma dica: pra ficar mais pythônico, você pode tirar os parênteses do if do seu código.

Answer (score 6):

Você não precisa de nenhuma biblioteca para isso, o Python por si só já possui ferramentas para a formatação em notação científica, basta utilizar o `e` na formatação:

```
>>> número = 123456789.123456
>>> print('{:e}'.format(número))
1.234568e+08
```

Ou pode utilizar as próprias *f-strings*:

```
>>> número = 123456789.123456
>>> print(f'{número:e}')
1.234568e+08
```

Se precisar limitar o número de casas decimais, pode fazer:

```
>>> número = 123456789.123456
>>> print(f'{número:.2e}')
1.23e+08
```

Para mais informações sobre a sintaxe de formatação, leia:

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

Comment: Deu certo o que voce me explicou e eu entedi mas esta tendo um pequeno problema
na formula é: Q = N*E. toda vez o resultado final da certo mas aquele o 10 elevado algum numero esta com o exemplo:
800 = n*e
5e+21

Comment: Estou querendo ajudar no seu problema, mas não consigo entender esse seu comentário.

Comment: O problema é:
n = int(input("Digite o valor de n "))
e = 1.6*10**-19
q = int(input("Digite o valor de Q "))
resultado = n*e


if(q !=0):
    resultado = q / e
    print(f'{resultado:.0e}')
else:
    resultado = n*e
    print(f'{resultado:.0e}')

800 = n*1,6*10elevado19
o resultado esta saindo 5e+21
esse e siginifica 10 queria que aparecer o 10 em vez da variavel

não sei se me entendeu

Comment: Me desculpe nao sabia que ficava horrivel em comentarios
sempre o resultado esta com o "e" pois em vez de ele dar o resultado em numero que é 10 ele esta dando a variavel e para representar o 10

Comment: Entendi agora. A notação científica em Python utiliza a letra **e** para representar o **10^**.

Comment: Então nao tem como ele representar o 10? Apenas a letra e?

Comment: Nativamente no Python, não. Você vai ter que buscar funções que alguém possa ter implementado. Altere a pergunta e a deixe mais específica. Diga na pergunta que você não quer usar o "e" padrão do Python, que você quer o "10^" ou qualquer outro tipo de representação. Provavelmente alguém já deve ter a solução para seu problema.

Comment: E só mais um último comentário. É de conhecimento comum na comunidade científica que esse "e" no meio de números dessa forma significa "10^". A não ser que você queira outra forma de visualização do dado, não vejo um motivo para trocar esse símbolo, que é o padrão.

Comment: Assim Obigado!!!

Comment: Muito Cool (+1); eventualmente `print(f'{número:.2e}'.replace("e"," 10^"))`

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
Tente utilizar o método **format_float_scientific** da biblioteca **numpy**.
Segue um exemplo:

```
import numpy as np 
number = 14366.081836478248
print(np.format_float_scientific(np.float32(number)))
```

Pode também escolher a precisão do valor:

```
print(np.format_float_scientific(np.float32(number), precision=3))
```

Verifique a biblioteca:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html