# Espaço entre o resultado (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Então, eu estou fazendo um exercício em que objetivo é que a maquina pergunte um numero e logo em seguida ele digita o numero de acordo com o seu valor. Por exemplo, se eu digitar "2" ele me da como resposta "22", se eu digitar "3" ele me da como resposta "333" e assim sucessivamente. Eu quero que entre os números fique um espaço, tipo se eu digitar "3" ele me devolva "3 3 3". Sei que isso parece ser bem simples, mas sou iniciante eu não estou conseguindo achar uma forma de fazer isso.

```py
n1 = int(input("DIGITE UM NUMERO : "))
n2 = str(n1)
print(n3*n1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Se você não se importar de sobrar um espaço em branco no final da *string* exibida, basta você concatenar (ou interpolar) um espaço em branco após o dígito que foi informado pelo usuário:

```
n1 = input('Digite um número: ')
n2 = int(n1)

print(f'{n1} ' * n2)
```

Ao informar o valor 2, a saída seria `'2 2 '`. Se quiser, você pode remover o espaço em branco das extremidades com o método `strip`:

```
print((f'{n1} ' * n2).strip())
```

E assim a saída passa a ser `'2 2'`, sem o espaço no final.

**Considerações importantes**

1. Não existe a necessidade de transformar a entrada do usuário para inteiro e depois novamente para *string*. Veja que da forma que eu fiz eu mantive a entrada original e apenas converti uma vez para inteiro;
2. Ao invés de concatenar o espaço em branco, utilizei a [interpolação de *string* através das *f-strings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878);

Fora isso, outra forma de obter o mesmo resultado é gerando uma *string* com a quantidade de elementos que você deseja e gerar a *string* final a partir dela, através do método `join`, que concatena todos os valores da lista utilizando uma *string* como separador:

```
print(' '.join(n1 * n2))
```

A parte `n1 * n2` irá gerar uma *string* `'n1n1n1...n1'`, sem espaços, com `n2` elementos e o método `join` irá concatenar todos os valores utilizando a *string* `' '` como separador, assim, o resultado também seria `'2 2'`.

Comment: Você é o Pythonista que o SOPT merece.

Comment: @LINQ Ou seria pythoniano? haha

Answer (score 3):

Eu não sou Pythonista, mas, pensei em algo assim: mantenha a string de entrada intacta, apenas faça a verificação se ela é realmente um número. Depois, multiplique a string de entrada concatenada com um espaço pela conversão para um número dela mesma.

```
entrada = input("DIGITE UM NUMERO : ")

if(entrada.isdigit()): 
    print((entrada + ' ') * int(entrada)) 
else:
    print(entrada, ' não é um número')
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/pt-so379788)**</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Na segunda linha a variável `int(n)` é convertida para *inteiro* antes de ser multiplicada por `n` que é uma *string*. Senão retornaria um erro.

O método `join` concatena um espaço entre caracteres da variável `n` antes de ser impressa na tela pelo `print`.

```
n = input("DIGITE UM NUMERO : ")
n = n * int(n)
print(" ".join(n))
```

Comment: Como o `input` já retorna uma *string*, eu manteria o retorno dela sem conversão para `int` e faria isso apenas na multiplicação: `n * int(n)`. Isso evitaria converter o valor de `n` para `int` e depois para `str` de novo sem necessidade.

Comment: Verdade, faz mais sentido. Não percebi quando copiei o código da pergunta. Grato pela contribuição!

Comment: Corrigi a minha resposta conforme a sugestão do Anderson Carlos Woss.