# Como escapar o caractere "{" em uma string formatada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatação

Como seria possível fazer com que uma string que utiliza o .format aceite a utilização de chaves como elementos da string e não o escape.

Ex: Gostaria que a variável s:

```py
interface = "alguma"
s = """{INTERFACE} {""".format(INTERFACE=interface)
```

Recebesse:

```py
alguma {
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa duplicar as chaves. Ao invés de apenas `{`, utilize `{{`:

```
interface = "alguma"
s = "{INTERFACE} {{".format(INTERFACE=interface)

print(s)  # alguma {
```

Se está utilizando a versão 3.6 ou superior do Python, dê preferências às *f-strings*:

```
s = f'{interface} {{'
```

Veja que é basicamente a mesma sintaxe que é utilizado com `format`, exceto pelo prefixo `f`.

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)
- [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/5878)

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> *Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`*.

Em tradução livre, *strings* formatadas possuem campos substituíveis cercadas por chaves. Qualquer coisa que não esteja entre chaves será considerado como texto literal, que será copiado para a saída sem modificação. Se necessita incluir o caractere das chaves como texto literal você poderá escapar ao duplicá-lo: `{{` e `}}`.