# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, o que aconteceu?

Tags: python, string, concatenação-de-string

Estou usando Python 3.7.4, tentei escrever de várias maneiras diferentes e nada funcionou.

```
character_name = "Johnny"
character_age = "64"
print(+character_name "is cool.")
print("And he is " character_age " years old.")
```

Erro:

> ```
>     print(+character_name "is cool.")
>                                    ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este código é quase aleatório. Existem regras a serem seguidas para escrever um código, não pode escrever do jeito que bem entende. Assim funciona:

```
character_name = "Johnny"
character_age = "64"
print(character_name + " is cool.")
print("And he is " + character_age + " years old.")
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HnPuWW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Concatenationpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Concatenation.py).

Alguns problemas aí:

- Tinha um operador de adição, que neste casos seria considerado concatenação logo no começo da expressão dentro dos parenteses da função, e isto não faz sentido, este operador é binário e espera um operando na esquerda e outro na direita, não pode ter nada na esquerda (neste caso ele até está trabalhando como operador unário que é só para confirmar que algo é positivo e só pode ser usado com números, não com textos).
- Depois você parece querer concatenar uma variável com um literal *string*, e não tem o operador, provavelmente porque usou ele no lugar errado.
- Aí em seguida nem usou o operador para concatenar a variável com as *strings*, tem que ter operadores.
- O ideal é usar uma forma de interpolação do que concatenar na maioria das situações.

Pode ler mais em [Como fazer interpolação de string em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/101).

Seria bom dar uma estuda em como funciona a sintaxe e entender o que cada parte faz, não tente juntar trechos aleatórios no código, isto não é programar.

Comment: Vale comentar que existe o operador `+` unário também, só não se aplica nativamente em *strings*, como é o caso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o operador mais sem sentido já criado antes que uma linguagem teve a péssima ideia de fazer e as outras copiaram