# Python não avança e não apresenta erro depois de converter string em float, como resolver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conversão-de-tipo

Estou recebendo a string `24.120185722369005` de um tópico do MQTT(HiveMQ), porém ao converter para `float`, ele ignora o resto da função.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    
        temperatura = msg.payload.decode()
     
        print('-----------------------------------------------')
        print('NUMERO DE ENTRADA :'+temperatura)
        
        try:
            print('tentando converter')
            temperatura = float(temperatura)

        except ValueError:
            print('bugado')

        #DEPOIS DAQUI ELE NÃO FAZ OS COMANDOS ABAIXO, MAS NÃO MOSTRA ERRO.
    
        print('temperatura convertida: '+temperatura)
    
        print('----------------------------------------------2')
    
        # Validar temperatura de entrada para enviar on/off
        if temperatura > float(50.00):
            print('passando o OFF')
        elif temperatura < float(50.00):
            print('Passando o ONN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro não ocorre ao tentar converter, o número é convertido para float normalmente. O problema está nesses 2 prints:  `print('NUMERO DE ENTRADA :'+temperatura)` e  `print('temperatura convertida: '+temperatura)`. O problema é que você não pode concatenar string com float.

O certo seria: `print('NUMERO DE ENTRADA :' + str(temperatura))` e `print('temperatura convertida: '+ str(temperatura))`

O seu código, arrumando os problemas que falei, ficaria assim:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    temperatura = msg.payload.decode()

    print('-----------------------------------------------')
    print('NUMERO DE ENTRADA :' + str(temperatura))

    try:
        print('tentando converter')
        temperatura = float(temperatura)

    except ValueError:
        print('bugado')

    #DEPOIS DAQUI ELE NÃO FAZ OS COMANDOS ABAIXO, MAS NÃO MOSTRA ERRO.

    print('temperatura convertida: '+ str(temperatura))

    print('----------------------------------------------2')

    # Validar temperatura de entrada para enviar on/off
    if temperatura > float(50.00):
        print('passando o OFF')
    elif temperatura < float(50.00):
        print('Passando o ONN')
```

Comment: Você não tem ideia do quanto me ajudou Brother, Deus te abençoe. Testei e funcionou. Eu pesquisei bastante, mas não sabia onde estava o problema. Agradeço de coração.

Comment: De nada, cara. Tmj

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você está concatenando uma string com um número, mas você só pode concatenar com outra string.

Só que em vez de transformar o número em string, como sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469148/112052), você pode usar outras opções - na minha opinião melhores - para conseguir o mesmo resultado.

A primeira é usando [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print('temperatura convertida: {}'.format(temperatura))
```

E a segunda é usando [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) (disponível para Python >= 3.6):

```
print(f'temperatura convertida: {temperatura}')
# repare no "f" antes das aspas
```

Outra vantagem destes métodos é que você pode, se quiser, usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) (caso queira limitar a quantidade de casas decimais, alinhar à direita ou à esquerda, etc).

Saiba mais lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/264702/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/112052).

---

Outro detalhe, fazer `float(50.00)` é redundante e desnecessário. `50.00` já é um número e convertê-lo para número não é necessário. Tanto que o código abaixo imprime "True":

```
print(50 == float(50.00)) # True
```

Então faça apenas `if temperatura > 50` que é o suficiente.