# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting (python)

Tags: python

Sou novo em programação, estou tentando fazer um programa que verifica se um numero inserido é primo, pra isso estou verificando se o resto da divisão do numero por numeros primos é zero.

```
def primo():

numero = input("Digite seu numero: ")

    if numero%2 == 0:
        print ("Seu numero não é primo")
    elif numero %3 == 0:
        print ("Seu numero não é primo")
    elif numero %5 == 0:
        print ("Seu numero não é primo")
    elif numero %7 == 0:
        print ("Seu numero não é primo")
    else:
        print ("Seu numero é primo")
```

mas estou recebendo o erro TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting na linha do primeiro "if". O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 1):

Basta converter para inteiro sua entrada

```
numero = int(input("Digite seu numero: "))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que o retorno da função [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#input) é sempre uma *string*:

> `input([prompt])`
>
> *If the `prompt` argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that**. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.*

E no Python o tipo *string* possui o operador `%` que faz a formatação. Por exemplo, se você faz `'%s %s' % ('Anderson', 'Woss')` terá a *string* final  `'Anderson Woss'`. Sobre o operador e outras formas formatar uma *string* ver:

- [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878)

Como a intenção é trabalhar com números, basta você criar uma instância de `int` a partir da sua *string*:

```
numero = int(input('...'))
```

E, assim, o operador `%` será resto de divisão como esperado e não mais um operador de formatação.