# Melhor forma de realizar o comando print

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estou estudando sobre Python a pouco tempo e aprendi a exibir um valor em print de três formas:

1. `%`
2. `'{}'.format(exemplo)`
3. `f' {exemplo} '`

Existe uma forma mais *pythônica* ou cada forma é aplicável em uma situação?

Comment: ok, desculpe. Não tinha encontrado nada parecido.

Answer (score 0):

O `{}.format("variavel")` é a melhor forma. E você pode realizar calculo e condições dentro da `()` parentese e formatar a saída das `{}` chaves.

Comment: E por quais motivos é melhor?

Comment: Porque permite simplificação no código e melhor manutenção futura, princialmente se você deixar o código para um outro programador realizar manutenção futuramente. O Python aceita outra forma de declarar variavel, mas por convenção ela tende a entrar em desuso e permanecer apenas o formato "format'. Consegui te ajudar Anderson?

Comment: Sim, poderia complementar sua resposta com todas essas informações? Atualmente ela está baseada em achismo sem nenhuma fundamentação. E quanto às *f-strings*, o que diz delas?

Comment: Então, não é achismo não. Na época li um artigo explicando esse conceito não estou encontrando o link agora, posso nao estar sendo exato, você tem razão. Encontrei essa fonte https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format acredito que possa te ajudar mais.

Comment: Sei que não é achismo, mas sua resposta atual é pois você não colocou nenhuma fundamentação nela.  Você só disse "X é melhor", mas não disse o motivo. Também te convido a ler o tópico [O que utilizar para formatar uma string, % ou format?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262184/o-que-utilizar-para-formatar-uma-string-ou-format)

Comment: Anderson, obrigado.