# Em que ocasião eu uso o "%d" em uma linguagem python?

Tags: python

Para que serve o "%d" em linguagem de programação Python?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262184/5878

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `%d` é um *placeholder* (marcador de posição). Ele é usado para reservar valores (números) em um vetor.

Por exemplo:

```
print ('%s comprou %d laranjas' % ('Mikael', 12))
```

A saída fica:

```
Mikael comprou 12 laranjas
```

Veja que no exemplo acima também inseri o `%s`, que é utilizado para reservar strings (palavras).

Comment: entendi, muito obrigado!!

Comment: @MikaelPereira Se a resposta te foi útil, você pode marcá-la como correta usando o ✓ do lado esquerdo da publicação.

Answer (score 5):

Se você tá falando em formatação de strings, isso é um *placeholder* para números. A apresentação na *string* formatada sempre vai ser um número inteiro, mesmo que o parâmetro seja um número de ponto flutuante. Desta forma difere de usar **`%s`** que sempre vai mostrar o número na "forma original".

Existem vários outros marcadores de posições. [Você pode ver mais na documentação.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

Ex.:

```
nome = 'LINQ'
idade = 155.512
print('%s tem %d anos -- %s' % (nome, idade, idade))
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/pt-so382450)</sup>

Saída:

> LINQ tem 155 anos -- 155.512

Answer (score 4):

Vamos por partes e tentar entender o significado de cada **carácter** do algoritmo, pois tudo isto passa por um **compilador** e cada **carácter**, **palavra** e ou **símbolo** **possui o seu significado**.

**% (Operador de formatação de string)**

> **Formata a string de acordo com o formato especificado e também serve para calcular módulo**. Mas no nosso caso o **carácter** **`%`** é o que **marca o início do especificador**. **A sua Sintaxe é a seguinte:** **`% [key] [flags] [largura] [. precisão] [tipo de duração] [tipo de conversão] % [valores]`**

**Carácter d**

> ***Pode ser*** o **carácter** de uma **string** **`'d'`** ou no nosso caso, onde o **carácter** **`%`** vem ***primeiro*** e logo em seguida o **carácter** **`d`** vem a sua ***direita***, **isto significa o seguinte:** **`d`** é o **tipo de conversão** onde faz a ***sinalização do tipo de conversão*, que afeta o resultado de algum tipo de conversão, no nosso caso um *inteiro decimal assinado***.

**Um exemplo em funcionamento**

```
login = input("Login:")
senha = input("Senha:");
modulo = 100 % 2

print("O usuário informado foi: %s, a senha digitada foi: %d" %(login, senha))
print("O usuário possui um percentual de 0%")
print("O módulo de 100%2 é %d" %(modulo))
```

**Repare que você utilizou o carácter % de diversos modos diferentes:**

```
%(var1, var2)
%s e %d
0% e 100%2
```

**Você pode aprender mais na [documentação oficial da linguagem](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html).**